# Updating a changing Friend List that currently only gets called from an Activity's onCreate?

Tags: php, android, database, listview, navigation-drawer

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible. Bear with me as I'm still quite inexperienced with Android.

I've created a side panel drawerLayout that displays a Friend List for users of my application. This includes sent requests and received requests:

[image]

So far, every time the activity is created, a PHP request to the remote server is populating this list with friend of all status types, like so:

MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, populateFriendList());

I'm going to have buttons beside each friend in the list that can accept requests, decline them, etc. As an example: when confirming a friend, I've been able to remove them from the 'Sent Requests' section of the list view, and even update the database to reflect this.

But how am I supposed to update the ListView to then see the most up-to-date friendList, with the newly confirmed friend as a friend?

Worth noting is that rotating the device causes the friend list to update as the onCreate method is called again, meaning populateFriendList() gets called once more. I appreciate that this way probably isn't wise, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to handle this.  You could use GCM to send a push notification when there is a new friend request, or you can do long polling in a service pinging your server every interval to see if there is a new request.

your rotation is calling onCreate() every time because thats what's happening in the activity.  You can override OnConfigurationChanged() and that should handle rotation changes.

You can call onNotifyDataSetChanged() to let the adapter know there there is new data to be viewed.

Comment: Already got the onNotifyDataSetChanged part handled. I'm thinking the interval'd service might be necessary. I found this example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Is this as simple as it gets?

Comment: Vogella.com has great tutorials there!!!  You might want to do a service start_sticky so it always runs and you get the most up to date information.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try that out and let you know how I get on.